# Visual Studio 2015: adding specific snippet into code-editor context menu

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

Is there a way to add an execution of the *specific* code-snippet (#region snippet in my case) into the context menu that appears when you right-click in the code editor?

Yes, I know about "Surround with..." command that I can insert into the context menu, but it pops up the list and then requires you to select a snippet from it, and I would like to optimize the process, because I'm using this particular snippet very often.

Answer (score -1):

I must strongly discourage you from using regions. Better learn OOP and clean-code principles, study your code and think about how to make it better without regions.

- [are-regions-an-antipattern-or-code-smell?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53086/are-regions-an-antipattern-or-code-smell?newreg=2b87319a57984b55a2d240b81a8a14aa)
- [c-regions-is-a-design-smell](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/12/08/c-regions-is-a-design-smell/)
- learn from the best: [Uncle Bob](https://cleancoders.com/)

Comment: I don't see how these two notions ("refine code with collapsible areas" and "learning OOP") relate to each other. Thanks for your suggestion, but that was not my original question.

Comment: An individual following the OOP principles writes code that does not need much of collapsing. I know that I'm not answering your question, I don't want you to use those damn regions and instead proposing other way.

Comment: Let's put it this way: using regions is my fetish. Even if it's a simple auto-property definition, I prefer it to be collapsed into region. What's wrong with this? :)

Comment: Man, good luck with this approach. I admit that there is small chance that you are right and the best brains in the world are wrong but I highly doubt it. Make a research on usage of regions. In the end you'll do whatever you want anyway.

Comment: And I admit that there is nothing in common between my preferences in code formatting and best-brains' thoughts about OOP principles. So, I think we're done here. :)